# PHP to Correct TinyMCE URL conversions

Tags: php, tinymce

TinyMCE used in a custom CMS, converts ampersand in the urls to html entities like this:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=15.44,-14.57&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=250x180&amp;sensor=false" alt="map" />
```

This image results in error "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'size' parameter."

I could not change TinyMCE behaviour (nothing worked).

Alternatively, I would like to use PHP to find-replace all href / src before saving to DB.

How do I code in PHP to search the string $post for href / src urls and find ampersand html entity codes and replace it with "&" ?

I tried examples using preg_replace but could not get it to work.

Comment: Sometimes issues with Tinymce come because old version of PHP. I solved lot of problems installing PHP last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, hope it helps someone.

```
$str = '<a href="https://some.com/?m=1&amp;z=2&amp;s=3&amp;r=f">some text</a><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=136.22,-186.74&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=250x180&amp;sensor=false" alt="map" />';

$re = '/(href|src)=("[^"]*")/'; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match){
    $conv = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $match);
    $str = str_replace($match, $conv, $str);
}

echo $str; // &amp; in url converted to &
```